# System Crash When Overriding shouldInterceptRequest in WebViewClient

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

Goal:

Override all requests made by a WebView and make the request myself (eventually set up a proxy).

Code:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url == null || url.trim().equals(""))
        return null;

    final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
    final HttpUriRequest httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
        final Header[] headers = response.getHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE);
        String mimeType = "";
        String encoding = "";
        if (headers != null && headers.length > 0) {
            final String type = headers[0].getValue();
            final int semicolonIndex = type.indexOf(';');
            if (semicolonIndex != -1) {
                mimeType = type.substring(0, semicolonIndex).trim();
                encoding = type.substring(semicolonIndex + 1).trim();
                final int equalsIndex = encoding.indexOf('=');
                if (equalsIndex != -1)
                    encoding = encoding.substring(equalsIndex + 1).trim();
            } else
                mimeType = type;
        }

        return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, response.getEntity().getContent());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The requests all seem to go through just fine, but eventually I get a stack trace with one of the two following issues:

```
3 15:07:28.650 E/InputDispatcher( 3981): channel '40d76268 com.secure.browser/com.secure.browser.SecureBrowserActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-03 15:07:28.650 E/InputDispatcher( 3981): channel '40d76268 com.secure.browser/com.secure.browser.SecureBrowserActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

which is apparently indicative of the operating system running out of file descriptors (fid)

or

```
01-03 15:29:36.810 I/DEBUG   ( 5798):     5903cd34  ac81c0b7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-03 15:29:38.380 I/DEBUG   ( 5798): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
01-03 15:29:38.380 I/BootReceiver( 3981): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_07 to DropBox
```

(SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)

Which means I think means that the OS is running into low level issues.

I am using 3.0 + so the function should be supported.

This mostly fails when I turn javascript on, or after browsing for a while without javascript.

Comment: in your catch blocks put `e.getSuppressed()` in all. then re-run the code and reply if it worked.

and also reply if you're using `WAKE_LOCK` or not.

Answer (score 1):

The method is deprecated. Try other signature of same method.